# Setting raster symbology to standard deviations in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I have an ArcPy routine and I would like to set the symbology of a derived raster to standard deviations, so that I can then reclassify on that basis and convert to polygons. Is this possible? I looked at the documentation and it appears the options in symbology are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the verion of ArcPy, but this option to set class breaks for the raster layer and seems available to most versions.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/rasterclassifiedsymbology-class.htm

You can manually set the class breaks to standard deviations. Just subtract or add the standard deviations to the mean of the raster.

Standard deviations can be calculated easily enough either through ArcGIS

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-raster-properties.htm

Or converting to a numpy array and using numpy to calculate the standard deviations.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm

Finally, if the standard deviations are already known and in a layer that you have available, then you can replace a raster layer's source using this approach:

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012251